# Parameter passing ByRef with VB6 + Windows 7

Tags: windows, vb6, parameter-passing, byref

I've worked with VB6 for many years now but I bumped into something rather strange and I cannot confirm this result myself. So I'd like to know if the output of the following code is going to be

> 7
>
> 7

or

> 7
>
> 6

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
Dim V As Integer
V = 6
Call AddV(V)
Print V

End Sub

Sub AddV(ByRef P As Integer)
P = P + 1
Print P

End Sub
```

On my system (Windows XP + VB6), this works as expected. So I get the first output. However, I've seen the same program on Windows 7 + VB6 and the output is not the same.

Can someone please explain why this is so? However, the same thing worked just fine on VB 2008 + Windows 7. I thought that call-by-value and call-by-reference were standard parameter passing techniques in any language/OS.

Thanks!

EDIT: cmdOK is a command button.

Comment: I get the same result (7 7) on VB6+XP and on VB6+Win7 (same exe).  
Per Hans' description, if I run it with the Call keyword removed then I see the expected result of (7 6) in both OSes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
V = 6
Call AddV(V)
```

You are not going to observe this behavior with this code.  Nor can this have anything to do with the Windows version, it isn't involved with VB6 code execution.  There is however an easy explanation for your observation.  Your code probably looked like this:

```
V = 6
AddV (V)
```

In other words, no *Call* keyword.  Now something pretty horrible happens in VB6.  The parentheses no longer mean the same thing anymore.  You don't use parentheses to call a Sub, only when you call a Function.  Instead, they become part of an *expression*, the same kind of parentheses you'd use when you'd write `Print 4 * (5 + 6)` for example.  It produces a **copy** of the value of V.  The called procedure updates that copy, it no longer affects the value of the V variable.

While this was intentional, the feature was a major bug factory and was not carried forward into VB.NET.  Parentheses now always mean the same thing in a procedure call and you use them regardless of whether the called procedure is a Sub or a Function.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs... Please note that my code in the question is the exact thing I took from my VB program on Windows XP. For me, it produces the 'expected' output (which is the first). Have you tried this code on Windows 7 with VB6? If you did, what was the result?

Comment: Of course not.  It is going to take an order from the Prez to get me to wipe my Win8 machine and install VB6.  I gave you an excellent explanation for a trap that many VB6 programmers have fallen into, clearly I think you are just another victim.  Show me a screenshot.

Comment: Blatant off-topic .Net proselytizing aside (think "getting bitten by a zombie") I'd have to agree.  This is nothing the OS version has anything to do with.

Comment: Hmm, no, why this doesn't happen in VB2008 was an explicit ask in the question.